# Question about mysql_fetch_array?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

How does mysql_fetch_array work?

Is it a stack/queue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It fetches the current row from the open cursor and hydrates it into an array using one or both of two methods:

- MYSQL_ASSOC - column names as array key
- MYSQL_NUM - column position as array index

See [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_(databases)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_%28databases%29)